# Is working too much (for money) a form of indulgence?

Tags: right-intention, money

I have a tendency to take up many job opportunities for the sake of earning money beyond what is necessary. Can working too much for monetary gain be considered a form of indulgence that leads to the development of greed?

Sutta or other textual references are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Buddha admire wealthy people who earn their wealth by right lively hood.
However he encourage people to use their wealth wisely for their benefit and the benefit of others.
Link to two major Suttas are:

http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.31.0.nara.html

http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/snp/snp.1.06.nara.html

Answer (score 1):

[SN 3.19](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn03/sn03.019.than.html) criticises earning money for the sake of it & miserly hoarding money.

The [Rāsiyo Sutta (12)](http://awake.kiev.ua/dhamma/tipitaka/2Sutta-Pitaka/3Samyutta-Nikaya/Samyutta4/41-Gamini-Samyutta/01-Gamanivaggo-e.html) praise people who can make lots of money when they are not attached to the money and, in particular, spend the money for the benefit of themselves & particularly others.

Other suttas that mention the beneficial necessity of money are [Anana Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.062.than.html) & [Sigalovada Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.31.0.nara.html)

Therefore, the Pali suttas praise the having & using of money for beneficial purposes & criticise making of money motivated by greed.